# Rank athletes by weighted criteria

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a structure. that consist of the following:

```
Athlete A         Athlete  B     Athlete C
speed=10          speed=12       speed=6
endurance=60      endurance=59   endurance=64
```

I would like to rank the strength of those three Athletes based on their speed and endurance. I would like to give a slightly greater weight (0.6) to the endurance. Is there any algorithm that have a good complexity to solve this problem?

Comment: Would a sorting algorithm help you here like merge of insertion sort? You could sort by numerical values for endurance or derive a new number from speed and endurance and sort by that and get a rank. Or am I misunderstanding what you hope to accomplish here.

Comment: You will find that as soon as you specify *exactly* what you want (you leave us guessing so far), you will already have written down the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to rank the strength of those three Athletes based on their speed and endurance.

There is an infinite number of ways of doing that. The two [*lexicographic orders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and [*weighted sums*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_sum) are only a few examples.

What do you *really* want?

> I would like to give a slightly greater weight (0.6) to the endurance.

This suggests that you want (linear) weighted sums. If that is to make sense, you need to [*normalize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) your values to a shared scale. You don't give units or ranges, so I'll have to guess.

Normalizing with the maximum values in the sample and assuming that values $0$ are possible, a weighted sum that gives weight $p \in [0,1]$ to endurance and $1-p$ to speed looks like this:

$\qquad\displaystyle w(a) = p \cdot \frac{\operatorname{end}(a)}{64} + (1-p) \cdot \frac{\operatorname{speed}(a)}{12}$.

Implementing this is so [straight-forward](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/4c988dfcf225c6c637af) that it's barely worth being called "algorithm"; you'll certainly find nothing in a textbook that lays out the details for your. Just code it down.